# Error while trying to use fontawesome-webfont.woff in Font Awesome

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome in my project. I modified the font-awesome.css to point to my directory where the font files are stored. So now it looks like this:

```
src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
```

But the problem is that it throws error on my browser console for the statement `url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1')`. The error is:

```
GET http://localhost/***/***/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 400 (Bad Request)         fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1:1
GET http://localhost/***/***/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1 400 (Bad Request)      fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1:1
```

If I modify the statement to `url('fontawesome-webfont.woff')` then it works without any error. I found [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15382892/1047998) where user has same problem but no satisfactory answers are provided.

Anyone knows the reason for this? Also why are the additional parameters in font's URL provided for like `fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1` and `fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1`?

Answer (score 7):

I had nearly the same problem: the only `fontawesome-webfont.woff?=3.2.1` gives the error but another woff without version is loading with no problem and ttf with 3.2.1 was loaded with no problem.

I have added `MIME` type woff as `font/woff` to the application's `MIME` types. 
Getting 200 now.
Regards

Comment: First src line is to support IE9, but it needs this answers IIS configure fix. Second src line is for IE6-8. See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26992/if-i-have-only-woff-and-eot-what-browsers-am-i-supporting-with-font-face and http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems

Comment: this worked for me, but just wondering...why does this fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following MIME types :)
woff font/woff
woff2 font/woff2

Answer (score -3):

The reason of this issues is wrong path of fonts or missing required fonts.To fix the issue follow steps bellow

1: go to http://fontawesome.io/

2: download fonts, and extract downloaded zip file

3: go to fonts folder, copy fonts

4: past fonts to `http://localhost/***/***/`

hope it will be help full for you.