# URLs within CSS files broken with Grails resources plugin 1.2.7

Tags: css, grails, grails-resources-plugin

Recently upgraded a grails project to 2.3.7 and plugins to their newest, which has brought Resources plugin to 1.2.7.  This worked fine with Grails 2.1.2 and resources plugin 1.2RC3, but now it is not:

whenever I have a css file that references something via a URL like this

```
.checkbox-input-wrap.checked {
  background-image: url(/img/uniform-assets/checkbox.png);
}
```

On the webpage it leads to this error (it is leaving 'resource:/' on the front of the URL)

> GET resource:/img/uniform-assets/checkbox.png net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue. Able to access any resource with resources 1.2.7. Can you add more info to debug?

Comment: I have the same problem with grails 2.3.6 and resources plugin 1.2.7 and haven't been able to fix the issue.
Works fine with plugin version 1.2.1 so I just reverted for time being.

Comment: @ascu downgrading has worked for me also.  Going to poke around a bit more.

Comment: I have a very similar problem with 2.3.7 and the 1.2.7 version of the plugin. Fonts aren't loading -- GET resource:/fonts/open-sans/Bold/OpenSans-Bold.svg net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to my comment earlier, this wasn't an issue for me because by default all resources under `/images`, `/css` and `/js` are served as adhoc resources in Grails and I was testing with a `.png` file from `images`.

I came across this issue again from my colleague which made me think twice. :) In his case, he was trying to access fonts from `/fonts` which is provided by a plugin used in the app.

Before trying the below answer, I tried to disable css rewriting by adding the below configuration:

```
//Not required
//grails.resources.rewrite.css = false
```

but it made no sense for me as I was dealing with a `font` resource.

Ultimately, adding this as part of `Config.groovy` for `fonts` made the trick. For your case, you would need to do like below:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/img/**']
//If resource served from a plugin
//grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/plugins/**', '/img/**']
```

If you already have this configuration, it would look something like:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = [
    '/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/img/**'
]
```

But as I said you might not need adding adhoc includes for existing resources in a grails app.

Go ahead with

- `grails clean` (to be on the safer side)
- `grails run-app`.
- Clean browser cache (I would prefer an incognito mode in Chrome, if Chrome used)
- Hit app url

It should not complain about the resource any more.

Comment: I also noticed the issue with /fonts files.  I thought I had tried with an update to my adhoc includes but will try again given your success.

Comment: I hope you will hit a success this time. You might have added as `adhoc.patterns` instead of `adhoc.includes` because I was confused for a moment as well. :) @Pete

Comment: Works!  Note we are also using cached-resources and zipped-resources and all appears good.   It didn't work for me originally as my browser was caching something and I needed to shift+refresh after adding the proper adhoc includes (not usually necessary using cached-resources).