# Where to change grails.resources.adhoc.patterns

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am develping a website in Grails

the image location is at C:\website\web-app\img
the css location is at C:\website\web-app\css

My CSS

```
.footer-stay-connected a {
  width: 115px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url(../img/stay-connected.png);
}
```

I run-app in local, the background image gets changed

```
.footer-stay-connected a {
    width: 115px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(resource:/img/stay-connected.png);
}
```

This causes resource not found because now my browser is trying to find the image at

```
http://localhost/website/static/css/resource:/img/stay-connected.png
```

From this page, http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ["/images/*", "*.css", "*.js"]
```

I seems to me that this might be an issue with Resource plugin configuration.
It works when i renamed my image folder from "img" to "images"

Where can I find `grails.resources.adhoc.patterns`so i can change from "images" to "img"

Comment: Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623584/urls-within-css-files-broken-with-grails-resources-plugin-1-2-7

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to find it in `[app-name]\grails-app\conf\Config.groovy`