# Routing error with font-awesome assets in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, font-awesome, twitter-bootstrap-rails

The font-awesome css file is located in `app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.css` and yet the error is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.css"):
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Based on another Github answer (https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/535), `fontawesome-webfont.woff` is located in `vendor/assets/font` but the error is:

Started GET "/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 16:31:35 -0700

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff"):
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have tried pre-compiling the assets before running the app but that doesn't work either. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is the [general guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome) to using font-awesome with Rails.

However I usually just use [this gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) which does it for you.

Comment: Excelent ! I was using `font-awesome-sass-rails` gem that is not updated anymore, did not thing about searching for a most recent one. Thanks for the link

Comment: I got rid of the woff error but the .css still exists. I followed the guide and also added the gem. Any further ideas what could still be causing it?

Comment: You don't need the font-awesome.css it should be bundled along with the  gem so you can remove it from your stylesheets.