# Glyphicons with bootstrap 3.3.4 not working in rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have rails 4.2.1 application which uses bootstrap 3.3.x and glyphicons. I cant use boostrap-sass or any other gems for integrating bootstrap with rails because the original bootstrap.css has been modified by the designer. I also have a custom.css file.

I have renamed all the **css** files(application, bootstrap and custom) to use **scss** format. Currently, the bootstrap css is working fine but the glyphicons are not being displayed. I have replaced the font-face code in the bootstrap.scss to

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'));
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype');
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2')) format('woff2');
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) format('woff');
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')) format('truetype');
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')) format('svg');
}
```

Previously([fontawesome + rails 4.0.1 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988644/fontawesome-rails-4-0-1-not-working/21844932#21844932)), I did configure the scss files in rails to use different fonts and it did work. I tried the same approach in the current rails application but am not able to figure out as to why its failing. Here(https://github.com/prasadsurase/rails-fonts.git) is a sample rails application to check out the issue.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your SCSS. The `@font-face` should be declared as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'));
  src: url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2')) format('woff2'),
       url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) format('woff'),
       url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')) format('truetype'),
       url(font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')) format('svg');
}
```

Note that there are exactly 2 `src` specifications. The first `src` has one `url()`, and the second `src` has multiple `url()` declarations separated by commas, not semicolons.

Comment: if we replace the ; with , as u specified, getting "Invalid CSS after "  src": expected ";", was ": url(font-path..."" error.

Comment: I cloned your repo and made this change, and it fixed the problem. Pretty sure it works. :) Are you copying the `@font-face` code exactly from my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was stuck for hours.

Comment: can u pls add comments as to to why the second and later 'src's are seperate from the first one. Why are they grouped seperately from the first? thanks.

Comment: I suspect this particular ordering of the `src` declarations is to ensure compatibility with various browsers. I based my answer on the Bootstrap source code, found here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.4/less/glyphicons.less#L11