# Rails 4.2 / Bootstrap 3 : trying to use font-awesome ... wo success

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome-4

I am trying to use font-awesome, but upon running , I get the following error(s)

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff"):
....
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"):
....
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg"):
```

In my Gemfile  I have:

```
 gem "font-awesome-rails"  # https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails
```

in my framework_and_overrides.css.scss I have:

```
// import the CSS framework
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

In my application.css  I have:

```
/*
...
*= require font-awesome
*= require dashboard/framework_and_overrides
....
*/
```

I added in my application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

And I run rake assets:clobber , to start on a clean basis .. now way , same errors

Thanks for your enlightenments ...

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988644/fontawesome-rails-4-0-1-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove from application.css:

```
*= require font-awesome
```

In your **framework_and_overrides.css.scss** add the following lines at the bottom:

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out you have an issue with the routing of the asset. Rails creates paths to assets depending if they are pre-compiled or not. The safest way to make things work in all cases (both production and development) is to put the routes in font_url ,like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: font_url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: font_url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), font_url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), font_url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), font_url('fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Alternatively, you can link an external stylesheet (performance might get worse):

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , I guess you are targeting the gem 'font-awesome-sass'  ( sprockets does nt work w font-awesome-rails gem... ( I tried )  I removed the require, I added the 2 import lines and the asset.precompile...  but , same errors , same message ... btw , in development mode , the pre-compile is not performed isn't it ?...

Comment: I guess I found the error :   in my  style.css , I have 
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
}
... the url is wrong !!!!

Comment: I just updated the solution. Let me know if this works

Comment: That's it ... thanks for your answer ...  it's running fien , I got rid of this @font-face css entry .. ( I am reusing a template...)   as everything is handled by the font-awesome-sass gem ....