# Glyphicons Halflings and other font-based icons are not showing up on Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome, glyphicons

I am working on a Ruby on Rails web app using Font-awesome and Glyphicons icons on top of Bootstrap. The icons do not show up on Chrome. I can actually get them to show up by hovering over them OR start the inspector (i.e. inspect element). Has anyone seen this issue before? I am losing my mind here....

As you can see, the first two icons are showing because I hovered over them, the rest are not showing up!

[image: As you can see, the first two icons are showing because I hovered over them, the rest are not showing up!]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This any good? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome

Comment: It turns out that a javascript file was interering with it. It was a third party javascript file that a designer dumped in. I removed it and the problem went away... Thanks for your help, @BillyMoat