# What's the easiest way to add font-awesome in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I have followed the instructions from font awesome guide at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/ but the font doesn't appear to my html.erb page, instead it shows weird symbols.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I like the [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem best. It integrates FA into the asset pipeline and adds a `fa_icon` helper that you can use in your views.

Comment: thanks @ lot, this works like a charm at the first try

Answer (score 0):

What code are you using for your classes? You need to use 'fa', not 'icon' e.g.

```
class="fa fa-plus"
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `config/initializers/assets.rb` add next strings:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome-webfont.eot )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome-webfont.woff2 )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome-webfont.woff )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome-webfont.ttf )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome-webfont.svg )
```

in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` add

```
*= require font-awesome
```