# How to add SB-admin v2 in Ruby-on-Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, themes

I want to use [SB Admin v2 Themes](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) in my  RoR application. I downloaded it and I don't know what's next to do.

BTW, I have gem `bootstrap-sass` in my `Gemfile`.

Comment: I think you have to reed some tutorial. do you have any experience with some framework of any language?

Comment: Can you give me some link of sample tutorial? This is my first web application and first time using Ruby on Rails. Thanks. I tried to copy the **dist** folder but icon is not working i have to change _fa fa-user fa-fw_ to _glyphicon glyphicon-user_ and some sidebar function is not working also.

Comment: do you have any experience with some framework of any language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is:

1. Create an admin.html.erb layout with the base markup provided in index.html of the SB Admin 2 template
2. Take a look at the js and css files included in the template and put them in their corresponding dirs in vendor/assets
3. Add the corresponding requiere and import in application.js and application.scss manifests
4. Don't include the assets for Morris charts until you really need them.
5. In the file sb-admin-2.js remove the lines that add acttive css class for the menu.
6. Implement menu using simple-navigation gem. It would look something like

   ```
   # encoding: utf-8

   SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
     navigation.items do |primary|
       primary.item :dashboard, 'Inicio', admin_path, link_html: {icon_class: 'dashboard'}
       primary.item :clients, t_title('routes.clients'), admin_clients_path, link_html: { link_active: current_page?(admin_clients_path), icon_class: 'users' } do | clients |
         clients.item :clients_new, t_title('routes.new'), new_admin_client_path
       end
     end
   end

   SimpleNavigation.register_renderer admin_sidebar: Sb2AdminSidebarRenderer
   SimpleNavigation.config.selected_class = 'active'
   ```
7. Not last but somewhere between the steps above you'd create partials for side menu, navbar top, etc.

Comment: Thanks ^_^ so I am in the right path ^_^ this is what I am doing and I am not sure if I am doing it right. yeah I did not include Morris because Mentismenu will not work. One more thing, do I have to download font-awesome? Because I found out in the CSS, JS, and sample html, it is using **fa** in the icon instead of **glyphicon** Anyway thank for the help.

Comment: I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome) and it is now working ^_^ ... Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago I've developed a gem to add all the assets of the sb-admin-2 theme, here you have it: https://github.com/dreamingechoes/bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

`gem 'bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2'`

And then execute:

`$ bundle`

Or install it yourself as:

`$ gem install bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2`

Then, add this into your application.js file:

`//= require bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2`

and this line into you application.css file:

`*= require bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2`

And you're ready to use the HTML structure of the Bootstrap based admin theme SB Admin 2 on your Rails application.