# Why wont Font-Awesome icon load in my Rails App on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, font-awesome

I'm learning how to build rails apps, so bear with me on this question.

I've loaded font-awesome using the 'font-awesome-sass' gem.

In my CSS file, I load font-awesome:

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

This works great when I test my app locally. I'm using the `fa-users` icon. I call this in my html page using:

```
<%= link_to root_path, class:'navbar-brand' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
  Title
<% end %>
```

However, when I deploy my app to Heroku, the fa-user icon turns into a square.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> turns into a square

Means you don't have the supporting `webfont` compiled (explained in a second).

You need to make sure you've [compiled your assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), to allow the `CSS` to both read and use the `webfont` that's loaded by `font-awesome`:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Assets"
$ git push heroku master
```

---

We have several apps running `font-awesome` in a Heroku production environment.

To do it, we used the [`font-awesome-rails`](https://rubygems.org/gems/font-awesome-rails) gem (this includes nice [helpers](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers)):

```
<%= link_to fa-icon("users", text: "Title"), root_path, class:'navbar-brand' %>
```

We use the following SASS file:

[image: @import font-awesome]

Doing this works for us -- make sure you *precompile* (mentioned above), and it should work for you.

---

**Web Icons**

There are several web icon "frameworks" ([Ionic](http://ionicons.com/) and [Font-Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) are the most popular). These basically work in the same way -- they have a custom font which they've compiled into a [webfont](https://github.com/umhan35/ionicons-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/fonts).

This webfont is then made available in your app through a series of custom classes. These classes prepend a specific font "character" (icon) to the class with the [`:before`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) pseudoclass.

Thus, when you call [`fa-users`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.css.erb#L708) class, you're really getting this:

```
.fa-users:before {
  content: "\f0c0";
}
```

The bottom line is that you need to make sure both the `webfont` and the CSS stylesheets are precompiled properly before referencing either.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Since I'm new to rails I don't have a strong understanding about the precompile process, but I'll keep what you've said in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this code to your ".scss" file and don't care any gem or configuration stuff.

```
    @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this produces the same results as I am currently getting.

Comment: @Pete Sorry for later responce , but you may need to clear all precompiled files on heroku. And deploy with this fresh code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured all css files into assets properly ?
I think the error may happens due to faulty configuration of style sheets (CSSS) in assets pipline, the following links will help you sometimes to solve the issue.

1. [Rails: Using Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome)
2. [Easy ways to get Font Awesome 4.5.0 onto your website](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptom (squares instead of webfonts) but a different cause. Mine was due to a CORS issue with my CDN. To see if you have the same cause as mine, just open the web console and look for errors like `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku can't find the font folders. Here are a couple of solutions that helped me tackle same problem :

1. Make sure you precompile your assets locally via `rake assets:precompile` before deploying to Heroku. Also check `config.assets.compile = true` on `config/environments/production.rb`.
2. If that doesn't work, you can always go for Bootstrap CDN solution to be included in `<head>` tag of your layout files. This provides the same solution without loading the files from your server.:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   ```