# How to import font-awesome in tailwind css in the rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, font-awesome, tailwind-css

I am trying to import font-awesome in my rails application which uses tailwind css framework.Unfortunately instead of icons square boxes show up in my application.

Steps followed:

```
yarn add --dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free

application.scss
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";
```

I tried so many ways but not able to display icons. Can someone let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
# application.scss
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
```

Comment: How to include .css files instead of .scss files?

Comment: check the last answer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome#11053749)